# Database Design One Foreign Key mapped to Another Foreign Key

Tags: database

Am busy designing DB for web application, I got a situation where I got to create a backup table of sensitive information table when ever it got updates or change. As given in [image]

For A_B_Mapping_Backup table I would like to create a foreign key for the field AFeild1 and BField1, Is it better to do reference A_B_Mapping or individually Table A and Table B ?

Comment: maybe add a new PK to the A_B_Mapping table - then reference that

Comment: is thats the best way? Because AField1 and BField1 forms PK for this table.

Comment: best is subjective maybe. i prefer a unique single value key - if you use a compound key - then later someone adds another record with matching A and B but different Field values - then you're in trouble... and the developer doesn't know that's illegal by looking.. so now you need to make sure all other constraints are always defined and in force etc. 2 cents.